# How to append a character after any number followed by a dot in Vim using regex?

Tags: vim

I want to append a character after any number followed by a dot in Vim using regex.

Example (append -):

```
1. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.

4022. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Becomes:

```
1.- Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.

4022.- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Please help.

Comment: What  did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:%s/\(\d\.\)/\1-/g`

It changes this:

```
1. this 2. will
3_ do 4305. what 5.. you
ask 6*
```

to this:

```
1.- this 2.- will
3_ do 4305.- what 5.-. you
ask 6*
```

The way it works is to match and remember any digit `\d` followed by a dot `\.`
(the stuff between `\(` and `\)` is remembered for later use - these are called
capture groups). Then replace this with the remembered capture group using `\1`
and add a `-`. The `g` at the end makes happen for every match on each line.